# deque throws Segfault after 128 iterations

Tags: c++, deque

I don't have a clue why this function outputs `Segmentation fault` when `n >= 128`

Apparently, this was supposed to handle `long long n` to output the last digit of the sum of the first `n` Fibonacci numbers.

I don't ask for a solution, I know there're alternatives!

All I want to know is why the Segfault? Am I missing something? It's my first time to deal with `deque` btw.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;

int fibonacci_sum_deque(long long n) {
  if (n <= 2)
    return n;

  deque<int> sum(4);
  sum[0] = 0;
  sum[1] = 1;
  sum[2] = 2;

  for (long long i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
    sum[3] = (sum[2] + sum[1] + 1) % 10;
    sum.pop_front();
  }

  return sum[2];
}

int main() {
    long long n = 0;
    cin >> n;
    cout << fibonacci_sum_deque(n);
}
```

gdb output:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401861 in fibonacci_sum_deque(long long) ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000401861 in fibonacci_sum_deque(long long) ()
#1  0x000000000040342d in main ()
```

Comment: run under valgrind if you are on linux

Comment: You initialize the deque with 4 elements and pop `n-2` elements off

Comment: @Kevin excuse me, when did I pop the second element? I pop `n-1` element per iteration. It works well from `0` to `127`

Comment: Every iteration `sum.pop_front();` removes the first element from the deque. After 4 iterations the deque is empty, but you've wandered into undefined behaviors before that. Quick hack example: http://ideone.com/W6j3Pr

Comment: The loop runs `n-2` times and you never push anything else onto the deque (see my answer). `sum[3]` modifies an existing element. It doesn't append a new one.

Comment: @user4581301 I see. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You initialize `sum` with 4 elements and never add any more. But you do `sum.pop_front()` in a loop `n-2` times. You can either initialize `sum` with `n` elements or `push_back` a new element like this:

```
deque<int> sum(3);
sum[0] = 0;
sum[1] = 1;
sum[2] = 2;
for (long long i = 3; i <= n; ++i) {
    sum.push_back((sum[2] + sum[1] + 1) % 10);
    sum.pop_front();
}
return sum[2];
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked, thanks :) However, it looks like the technique is so slow at `long long n`.

Comment: @AssemAttia You may find a fixed size array with an index that wraps around when it hits the end of the array to be a faster approach than the deque without changing the overall algorithm (but shouldn't be by much).  There are faster algorithms that you can use though. A warning: I'm pretty sure you have some bad math in the algorithm at the moment. Check your numbers.